# setStatusBarHidden instance again the initial class project

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, statusbar

I have a very strange problem, I am developing an app for iPhone and iPad, the iPhone version I hide the status bar and the iPad version as there is more space, leave it visible.

It's very simple to hide it, just one line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

everything works, but I noticed that some methods of initial class were called 2 times, even I do not have to instantiate more than one vez.Fui thoroughly and found that the call of any class of the design method which hides the status bar, the class Home is instantiated again, and performs all of its methods.

I do not know what to do, it is something very strange, any suggestions?

Comment: If you're calling it after your view controller is displayed, then this is normal. It's displaying the view and then re-displaying it because the "screen" size changes.

Comment: Where, exactly, are you calling this line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call this line of code, when needed (i.e. on iPhone only), at the beginning of the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in you `UIApplicationDelegate` class, so it does not interfere with the following code. I believe you are calling this line in your controllers directly, and you probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: Got it, the fact is that I am calling this method in a view controller, but it is extremely nescessario he is called, it is an image viewer, like the iPhone camera roll, and I need the status bar becomes invisible while the user viewing the images.